# Conjoint analysis for continuous choice

Tags: conjoint-analysis

I am new to conjoint analysis and have been following a tutorial based on the `mlogit` package in R. However, I can't apply this modeling technique to my data for which my choice variable is a continuous measure. Is there any package and more importantly tutorial or reference for conjoint analysis with a continuous outcome variable?

Comment: That will be classic (rating) conjoint, which is more simple (than the choice-based conjoint). I believe many packages providing conjoint should include this option. I'm SPSS user and I know SPSS has this classic conjoint.

Answer (score 0):

Several options. `radiant` looks good to me and there is an easy to follow tutorial: https://bookdown.org/content/1340/8-conjoint.html as well as a shiny-app: https://vnijs.shinyapps.io/radiant/?SSUID=3dcff236d7

Then there is `conjoint`, which to me feels a bit more complicated. Still several interesting tutorials available: https://www.data-mania.com/blog/conjoint-analysis-in-r/ https://dzone.com/articles/doing-conjoint-analysis-in-r

You can also just use `lm` and do everything by hand, not too hard, but less convenient.